# Loading a very large table from mssql to vb.net memory

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012, large-data

So i got a very large table, with about 22 mio rows in it.. i wan to load them all into a vb.net application memory (i got 36GB of RAM, so i should be okay).

now for the connection not to timeout, i wanted to ask for the best way to load that large a table.

and if there was a way to give feedback to the application, on the process, as it might take a couple of minutes to do.

i normaly use the sqldatareader.. but is that okay to use at that large amount of data?

i tryed googling a little about this problem.. my reason to load an entire table into the memory is to analyze it faster, as i need to run some regex, and sorting on it, more then TSQL offers.

i hope anyone can help, as i'm kinda stuck with this

Comment: What means _into memory_? Do you want to fill a `List<Foo>` or a `DataTable` or what else?

Comment: You could load the rows using the LIMIT command of MYSQL and process rows 10000 by 10000.
Like first select with LIMIT 0, 10000, then LIMIT 10000, 10000 etc.
And to optimize the thing you can launch the fetching in a thread while you process the regex on the 10000 rows previously fetched

Comment: i was thinking to load it into whatever array (List, DataTable or event Array) that is wastest to run trough.. its proberly the datatable, to keep the structure intact.

Comment: thanks Koren, i'm going to try that :)

Comment: LIMIT does not exists in MS SQL and you should be fine to use DataReader

Comment: You can simulate LIMIT with MSSQL with 
SELECT TOP 10000 id FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10000 id FROM table). So you have équivalent of MYSQL LIMIT 10000, 10000

Comment: thanks.. i really needed some sort of LIMIT, as freezing the program for 10 minutes, with no word of news, simply dosn't work for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ROW_NUMBER` to partition the huge resultset into smaller chunks. Then you could report progress on every chunk. Therefore you could use a `BackGroundWorker` to update a `Label` and/or a `ProgressBar`. To determine the size of each group you can select the total-rowcount first. Use this as divisor for the the chunksize (1000 in the following sample):

Here is a working approach that fills a `DataTable` and select only small groups from the toal result using `LINQ`:

On button-click start the `BackGroundWorker`:

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Handle the `DoWork` event to load the data:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim tblData As New DataTable()
    Dim totalCount = 0
    Dim chunkSize As Int32 = 1000
    Dim countSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tabData"
    Dim dataSql = "WITH CTE AS(SELECT d.*, rn=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY d.idData) FROM dbo.tabData d) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowEnd;"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
        Using cmdCount = New SqlCommand(countSQL, con)
            con.Open()
            totalCount = DirectCast(cmdCount.ExecuteScalar, Integer)
        End Using
        Dim chunks = Enumerable.Range(0, totalCount).
            GroupBy(Function(i) i \ chunkSize).
            Select(Function(grp, index) New With {
                       .RowStart = grp.Min() + 1,
                       .RowEnd = grp.Max() + 1,
                       .GroupNum = index + 1
                   })
        For Each chunk In chunks
            Using cmdData = New SqlCommand(dataSql, con)
                cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowStart", chunk.RowStart)
                cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowEnd", chunk.RowEnd)
                Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdData)
                    da.Fill(tblData)
                    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Math.Ceiling(chunk.GroupNum * chunkSize / totalCount))
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100)  ' all data loaded '
    End Using
End Sub
```

Update the label and/or the `ProgressBar` on every chunk and finally:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & " Percent loaded"
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.ProgressLabel.Text = "100 Percent loaded. Finished."
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot, this is much better then what i came up with myself, i was doing soo many methodes :)

Comment: i seem to have some problems loading the sql.. it takes about 5 minutes for each 1000 rows, i guess the code is too heavy for all thouse rows :(

Comment: @Droa: What column are you using for ordering, the PK-column? I have tested the code above with a table that has 15 Million records until the `DataTable` contained 1Million rows and that took 5 minutes.

Comment: i have a uniqueidentifier to be the id.. it's never been a problem before

Comment: I have tested the code above with a table that has 16 million rows until the `DataTable` contained 1 Million rows and that took 5 minutes. `idData` was the primary key of the table. Have you tested the sql in SSMS?

Comment: it took 7 minutes and 21 sec to execute in SSMS

Comment: @Droa: So it took more than 7 minutes to get 1000 records via `ROW_NUMBER` in ssms? That takes less than 2 seconds directly in ssms for me. Maybe you want to ask another question since this seems to be only database related.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42784/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-droa)

Comment: it might be the server struggling.. it wasn't build for that large databases.. and it is running express.
i might just convert it to our Live database server, to run it faster, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: thanks it works now, i had forgotten to add my id column as a unique.. its done now, and runs the query in 5 secs now :)

Comment: Guys, I have the same question but want to reproduce it in C# and to use a label to show percentage. I'm not a very much experienced developer, could you navigate me with it? In chat maybe or personal contacts.